# Different behaviour at synonyms migrating from solr 3.6 to 4.0

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, synonym, solr4

I'm studying the migration from SolR 3.6 to 4.0.

I've developed a tiny system with no more than 2500 documents. Furthermore, I've developed more than 4100 tests to make sure that at every change, there isn't a deterioration in the functioning of the system.

For this migration, I have kept the default settings of Solr 4.0, just adding my own fieldType (I've seen a lot of new settings at schema.xml and solrconfig.xml).

Thus, in a first run without synonyms, the difference between versions 4.0 and 3.6 was just a sentence (a phrase that in 4.0 works better than 3.6) from 4100. However, if I include synonyms, the deviation becomes much more evident, with considerably worse results at 4.0.

My fieldType is as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_es_lemma" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.lnk" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.lnk" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="myownlibrary.solr.analysis.SpanishLemmaFilterFactory" dictionary="lang/avatar_dictionary/adj_num_ord-lex.src,lang/avatar_dictionary/basic-lex.src" ignoreCase="true"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.lnk" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.lnk" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="myownlibrary.solr.analysis.SpanishLemmaFilterFactory" dictionary="lang/avatar_dictionary/adj_num_ord-lex.src,lang/avatar_dictionary/basic-lex.src" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The file with synonyms is the same at both versions.

Is there any difference between how synonyms are used at 4.0 and 3.6? Do I have to specify them in a different way at 4.0?

Comment: why are you using SynonymFilterFactory on both sides (index time and query time). Generally SynonymFilterFactory is used only once, either index time or query time but not both.

Comment: @randroid, afaik the recommended configuration is to use synonyms in both sides with the proviso that at _index time_ are used with **expand=true** and at _query time_ with **expand=false**.

Comment: I am not sure what is the advantage of using it on both sides.

Comment: For example we have "Television, Televisions, TV, TVs" and we index the term "tv", then the indexed value will have all 4 terms (Television, Televisions, TV, TVs), now when we search for "TVS", during query time analysis it will pick the first item (Television) from the synonyms, as we have expand=false. If we did not have synonymFilterFactory at query time, then it will simply match the query term, which should work as we have expanded synonyms at index time.